# java Myabtis exceptionjava Myabtis exceptionjava Myabtis exception

Tags: java, orm, ibatis

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'verionStartDate' in 'class cn.sto.compass.domain.transferfee.request.TransferOutportOperQuery'

tell me how to make it out?